# Rails 3: loops and plucking items out best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a small app that allows for users to add a product (or subscription) to their cart. Upon creating their account, the new user is sent to a "bundle" page where it asks if they would like to add a different subscription to a different product altogether for a bundled price.

Here is where I am stuck: Upon submitting the user's credit card info I get slightly "lost in translation" when trying to setup the bundle pricing to submit to Authorize.net (I understand how to authnet, not the question here).

Here is what I have so far:

```
current_order.products.includes(:client).each do |product|
          transaction = current_order.submit_order_to_authnet(product)

            if transaction.result_code == 'Ok'
          new_group = Group.create!(:name => "#{current_user.full_name} #{product.title}", :type => 'school', :start_date => Time.now, :status => 'active', :site_id => 1)
          primary = session[:primary_product_id].eql?(product.id) ? true : false

          # Add subscription to Group
          new_group.add_subscription(product, current_order, transaction.subscription_id, 'active', primary)
          # Add Subscription to CurrentOrder
          current_order.subscriptions << new_group.subscriptions.last
          # Add user to NewGroup
          current_user.groups << new_group
          # Create New Group Admin
          new_group.group_admins.create(:user_id => current_user.id)
          # Send success email
          OrderMailer.checkout_confirmation(current_user).deliver
        else
          errors << transaction.result_code
        end
      end
```

I am trying to figure out the best solution when it comes to looping through each product in the users `current_order` because the second subscription in the users cart is the subscription that gets the discount applied too. I know I can write something like this:

```
current_order.products.includes(:client).each do |product|
    if current_order.products.many? and product == current_order.products.last
        # run discount logic
    else
        # continue with authnet for single subscription
    end
end
```

But I am just not sure if that is a best practice or not. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the only subscription that doesn't get discounted is the first one? Why not write it like this:

```
current_order.products.includes(:client).each do |product|
  if product == current_order.products.first
    # continue with authnet for single subscription
  else
    # run discount logic
  end
end
```